Proof of the Equivalence of Sequential Continuity and Continuity for a Distribution
Theorem 1.3.2
A linear form $u$ on $C_c^\infty(X)$ is a distribution if and only if $\lim_{j \to \infty} \langle u, \phi_j \rangle = 0$ for every sequence $\phi_j$ which converges to zero in $C_c^\infty(X)$ as $j \to \infty$.
Proof:

Necessity:
If $u$ is a distribution, then for any sequence $\{\phi_j\}$ converging to zero in $C_c^\infty(X)$, the pairing $\langle u, \phi_j \rangle$ converges to zero. Hence, $\lim_{j \to \infty} \langle u, \phi_j \rangle = 0$.

Sufficiency:
Assume $u$ is sequentially continuous. Suppose $u$ is not a distribution. Then there exists a compact set $K \subset X$ such that:
$$
|\langle u, \phi \rangle| > N \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi|
$$
for $\phi$ \in $C_c^{\infty}(K)$.
For each $N$, choose $\phi_N$ such that:
$$
|\langle u, \phi_N \rangle| > N \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|
$$
Define $\psi_N(x) = \frac{\phi_N(x)}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|}$. Notice $\psi_N$ is supported in $K$, and:
$$
|\partial^\beta \psi_N| \leq \frac{\sup |\partial^\beta \phi_N|}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|} \leq \frac{1}{N}
$$
for $|\beta| \leq N$. Thus, $\psi_N \to 0$ in $C_c^\infty(X)$ as $N \to \infty$.
However, from:
$$
|\langle u, \psi_N \rangle| \geq \frac{|\langle u, \phi_N \rangle|}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|} > \frac{N \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|} = N
$$
we get a contradiction. Hence, $u$ must be a distribution if it is sequentially continuous.


My Question:
In the proof of Theorem 1.3.2 from "Introduction to the Theory of Distributions" by F. G. Friedlander and M. Joshi, how is the bound:
$$
|\partial^\beta \psi_N| \leq  \frac{1}{N}
$$
derived? I understand that $\psi_N$ is defined as:
$$
\psi_N(x) = \frac{\phi_N(x)}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} \sup |\partial^\alpha \phi_N|}
$$
but I'm not sure how this leads to the desired bound.
Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated! If, for example, I could manage to replace the denominator with $N \cdot \sup \vert \partial ^{\beta} \phi_N \vert $ I would have obtained the estimate I need

The space $C_c^\infty(X)$ of test functions is the colimit in the category of locally convex spaces of the metrizable spaces $\mathscr D(K)$ of smooth functions with support in a finxed compact subset $K\subseteq X$. For metrizable spaces as a source, continuity is the same as sequential continuity (this is shown in the proof for the particular situation of $\mathscr D(K)$). Also, a linear map $T:E\to F$ on a colimit
$E=$colim $E_\alpha$ is continuous if and only all restrictions $T|_{E_\alpha}$ are continuous. Combining these two facts, you get without any calculations that a linear map $T:C_c^\infty(X)\to Y$ (with values in any locally convex space) is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous.

thanks for the answer, I’m not familiar with the concept of a colimit, but I can look up its definition. I was hoping to complete the calculation proof, as it would make it easier for me to adapt it to prove another theorem: that a sequentially continuous form on $C_c^m$ always restricts to a distribution of order $m$, and vice versa.

@Jochen: Since you know TVS theory very well, I meant to ask you what is the status of being sequential or not for $\mathscr{D}$. For other spaces of distributions, I have seen contradictory accounts in the literature, see my comments in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4961702/exact-meaning-of-a-bounded-set-in-the-space-of-tempered-distributions-mathcal  The related space $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}$ is sequential, and $\mathscr{D}$ is isomorphic to $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}s$ where $s$ is the space of rapidly decaying sequences.

I doubt that this is the right place to discuss this question but I strongly believe that there are sequentially closed linear subspaces of $\mathscr D$ which are not closed.

Suppose that there exists a compact set $ K $ such that the ratio
$$
\frac{|\langle u, \varphi \rangle|}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \sup_{x \in \Omega} |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|}
$$
is unbounded as $ \varphi $ ranges over $ \mathcal{D}_K(\Omega) $. Use this to select $ \varphi_m $ such that $ \langle u, \varphi_m \rangle = 1 $. For the definition of $ K $, for every $ m \in \mathbb{N} $, we have
$$
\frac{\langle u, \varphi_m \rangle}{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \sup_{x \in \Omega} |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|} > m,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \sup_{x \in \Omega} |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)| < \frac{1}{m}.
$$
Now, we have a sequence of test functions $ (\varphi_m) $ that converges to $ 0 $ in the topology of $ \mathcal{D}(\Omega) $, but the values $ \langle u, \varphi_m \rangle $ do not tend to $ 0 $.
Credits:
I reposted an answer from 'user357151' to another question titled 'A characterization of being sequentially continuous' by 'DonQuixote'. I did this so that anyone reading knows that I found an answer. Additionally, I didn't want to remove my post because I believe it is a valuable contribution. The title is explanatory, and the post contains two beautiful answers: one very elegant and abstract, and the other simpler and more direct.
